# Xubuntu: can't see certain directories

Tags: home-directory, symbolic-link

So I upgraded my Xubuntu to 20.04. I have the Documents and Pictures folders soft linked to a different partition (ln -s /opt/jdb/documents /home/jonathan/Documents and so on). Everything works fine EXCEPT - I can't see that folder from chrome/chromium - so for instance I can't attach files from that directory to gmail and so on. I've gone as far as `chmod 777` on both source and destination directories to rule out permissions issues, but I'm still resorting to dragging files to the desktop to attach to emails. Which is getting tiresome. Does anybody have any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Care to explain why you "export" your documents from home - where only you have access to - to a "system" directory where you don't have the appropriate rights?

Comment: Are you using the Chromium deb, snap, or some other install method?

Comment: @kanehekili: Good point, basic laziness. I keep personal files in a separate partition so that they survive system upgrades and re-installs, and I don't like mounting that partition at /home because it makes it harder to recover from a screwed up profile - which seems to happen a lot with system upgrades and re-installs. I decided to mount at /opt because I never have any packages that use that. It worked with 19.xx, but broke when I upgraded to 20.04. You're right, though, I'll try creating a separate mount point and link from there.